# Java random shuffle list with two elements using Collections.shuffle

Tags: java, random, collections

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class ShuffleList {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] file = {"1","2"};
    long seed = 3;
    ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(file));
    for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {
      Collections.shuffle(fileList, new Random(seed));
      seed = seed +1;
      System.out.println(seed + "," + fileList);
    }
  }
}
```

The output is 200 lines of [1,2], not random shuffle at all. In fact this is true for all seed < 4000.
Why is that? I tried with a list of 3 elements and seeds from 1 to 100 makes the list seemingly random. But what's wrong with a list of 2 elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't with `shuffle` - it's with `Random` with small seeds. Here's a program demonstrating that:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int seed = 0; seed < 4000; seed++) {
            Random rng = new Random(seed);
            total += rng.nextInt(2);
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

You'd *expect* an output of about 2000 - about half calls to `nextInt` should return 0, and about half should return 1. Instead, it's 4000 - *every* call returns 1.

Using seeds [10000, 13999) you get 240 - so vastly more of the calls return 0 than 1.

Using seeds [100000, 103999) you get 3226 - getting a bit better...

Using seeds [1000000, 1003999) you get 2105 - much better.

I don't know nearly enough about the maths of RNGs to say why this happens, but it does look like `java.util.Random` is kinda broken for small seeds.

Answer (score 2):

For a list of two elements, what shuffle does is swap one element with a random position :

```
    if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    }
```

This is where the Random instance is used (size is 2, so there's only one iteration) :

```
swap(list, 2-1, rnd.nextInt(2));
```

So all you proved is that for seeds between 3 and 203, the first call to `rnd.nextInt(2)` returns 1. Had you used a random seed or used the same Random instance in all your tests, you'd get a different result.

For example, changing `new Random(seed)` to `new Random(3)` (actually it would make more sense to create that instance once and pass it to Collections.shuffle) generates :

```
4,[1, 2]
5,[1, 2]
6,[2, 1]
7,[2, 1]
8,[1, 2]
9,[1, 2]
10,[1, 2]
11,[1, 2]
12,[2, 1]
13,[2, 1]
14,[2, 1]
15,[1, 2]
16,[1, 2]
17,[2, 1]
18,[1, 2]
19,[2, 1]
20,[2, 1]
21,[1, 2]
22,[1, 2]
23,[1, 2]
24,[2, 1]
25,[2, 1]
26,[2, 1]
27,[2, 1]
28,[2, 1]
29,[1, 2]
30,[1, 2]
31,[2, 1]
32,[2, 1]
33,[1, 2]
34,[2, 1]
35,[2, 1]
36,[2, 1]
37,[1, 2]
38,[2, 1]
39,[2, 1]
40,[1, 2]
41,[2, 1]
42,[1, 2]
43,[2, 1]
44,[1, 2]
45,[1, 2]
46,[2, 1]
47,[2, 1]
48,[1, 2]
49,[2, 1]
50,[2, 1]
51,[1, 2]
52,[1, 2]
53,[2, 1]
54,[2, 1]
55,[2, 1]
56,[2, 1]
57,[1, 2]
58,[2, 1]
59,[1, 2]
60,[1, 2]
61,[2, 1]
62,[2, 1]
63,[1, 2]
64,[2, 1]
65,[1, 2]
66,[2, 1]
67,[1, 2]
68,[2, 1]
69,[1, 2]
70,[2, 1]
71,[1, 2]
72,[1, 2]
73,[2, 1]
74,[1, 2]
75,[2, 1]
76,[1, 2]
77,[2, 1]
78,[1, 2]
79,[2, 1]
80,[1, 2]
81,[2, 1]
82,[2, 1]
83,[1, 2]
84,[1, 2]
85,[1, 2]
86,[2, 1]
87,[2, 1]
88,[1, 2]
89,[1, 2]
90,[2, 1]
91,[1, 2]
92,[1, 2]
93,[2, 1]
94,[1, 2]
95,[1, 2]
96,[1, 2]
97,[1, 2]
98,[1, 2]
99,[1, 2]
100,[1, 2]
101,[1, 2]
102,[2, 1]
103,[1, 2]
104,[2, 1]
105,[2, 1]
106,[1, 2]
107,[1, 2]
108,[1, 2]
109,[2, 1]
110,[2, 1]
111,[1, 2]
112,[2, 1]
113,[1, 2]
114,[1, 2]
115,[2, 1]
116,[2, 1]
117,[2, 1]
118,[1, 2]
119,[2, 1]
120,[1, 2]
121,[1, 2]
122,[1, 2]
123,[2, 1]
124,[1, 2]
125,[2, 1]
126,[1, 2]
127,[2, 1]
128,[2, 1]
129,[1, 2]
130,[1, 2]
131,[2, 1]
132,[2, 1]
133,[1, 2]
134,[1, 2]
135,[1, 2]
136,[2, 1]
137,[1, 2]
138,[2, 1]
139,[1, 2]
140,[2, 1]
141,[2, 1]
142,[1, 2]
143,[1, 2]
144,[2, 1]
145,[1, 2]
146,[1, 2]
147,[2, 1]
148,[2, 1]
149,[1, 2]
150,[2, 1]
151,[1, 2]
152,[1, 2]
153,[2, 1]
154,[2, 1]
155,[1, 2]
156,[2, 1]
157,[2, 1]
158,[2, 1]
159,[1, 2]
160,[1, 2]
161,[1, 2]
162,[1, 2]
163,[2, 1]
164,[2, 1]
165,[2, 1]
166,[1, 2]
167,[2, 1]
168,[2, 1]
169,[1, 2]
170,[2, 1]
171,[1, 2]
172,[2, 1]
173,[2, 1]
174,[1, 2]
175,[2, 1]
176,[1, 2]
177,[1, 2]
178,[2, 1]
179,[1, 2]
180,[2, 1]
181,[2, 1]
182,[1, 2]
183,[1, 2]
184,[2, 1]
185,[1, 2]
186,[2, 1]
187,[1, 2]
188,[2, 1]
189,[2, 1]
190,[2, 1]
191,[2, 1]
192,[2, 1]
193,[1, 2]
194,[2, 1]
195,[1, 2]
196,[2, 1]
197,[1, 2]
198,[2, 1]
199,[2, 1]
200,[2, 1]
201,[2, 1]
202,[2, 1]
203,[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Jon and Eran.

If you want to get your code to work, don't instantiate Random every time through the loop, create an instance before the loop and pass it in. Random is designed to be used this way, and not to have the seed changed before each call.

For example...

```
public class ShuffleList {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] file = {"1","2"};
    ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(file));

    Random random = new Random(3);
    for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {
      Collections.shuffle(fileList, random);
      System.out.println(fileList);
    }
  }
}
```